# symfony 2 - Facebook Bundle - FacebookProvider - How to use a service and Entity Manager in FacebookProvider ?

Tags: facebook, service, symfony, entitymanager

Everything is in the title, i use the FacebookBundle :

http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle

The log in with facebook work correctly and i want to use some services and instanciate some objects of my project to update my user datas.

//in my Facebookprovider

$user->setFBData($fbdata);

So before this line i want to use a specific service and use entity manager to fill in my $fbdata array with correct datas how i must do ?

is that it's the right way ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

have you defined your own  FacebookProvider in security.yml ?

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-integration-with-fosuserbundle.md

If so, you can inject any service you need to implement your logic in the class